# How do I take input from text file and use it as variable in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I want to insert in my script a value (string) that I would read from a text file.

For example: I have shell script

```
#!/bin/bash  
echo "Enter your name:"  
read name  
echo "...and now your age:"  
read age    

# example of how to use the values now stored in variables $name and $age  
echo "Hello $name. You're $age years old, right?"
```

and the input file (called input.in)

```
Priya  
26  
Thomas  
44
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add how the current script fails to do what you want?

Comment: I am running the script as : sh script.sh < input.in    Output :   Enter your name:
...and now your age:
Hello Priya. You're 26 years old, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to read input from a file, then the script really shouldn't be printing prompts.  Personally, I would strongly recommend dropping the prompts completely, but if you're going to use them, at the very least write:

```
test -t 0 && printf  'Enter your name: '
```

or (if your `read` supports it) `read -p`.

Since your input contains multiple records, it looks like you want:

```
while 
    read -p 'Enter your name: ' name \
    && read -p 'Enter your age: ' age
do
    echo "Hello $name. You're $age years old."
done
```